# warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-int’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Attempting to install the required gems for a project on Ubuntu 16 I ran into the error above. The gem causing it was `mini_racer 0.2.4`.

The code line causing the error is inside `/home/*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/mini_racer-0.2.4/ext/mini_racer_extension/Makefile`.

How do I remove the option `-Wimplicit-int` from that line when on the command to install the project gems `mini_racer 0.2.4` gets refetched?

```
current directory:
/home/*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/mini_racer-0.2.4/ext/mini_racer_extension
make "DESTDIR="
compiling mini_racer_extension.cc
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-int’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-tautological-compare’
linking shared-object mini_racer_extension.so
mini_racer_extension.so: final close failed: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:257: recipe for target 'mini_racer_extension.so' failed
make: *** [mini_racer_extension.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: Please check [this](https://github.com/discourse/mini_racer/issues/85) or [this](https://github.com/discourse/mini_racer/issues/37).

Try doing a `gem uninstall libv8` and retry installing `mini_racer`.

Comment: `Successfully uninstalled libv8-6.7.288.46.1-x86_64-linux
...
Successfully installed libv8-6.7.288.46.1-x86_64-linux
...
Successfully installed mini_racer-0.2.4
...
2 gems installed`


`*:~/Desktop/Studies/react-on-rails-demo$ gem which mini_racer
ERROR:  Can't find Ruby library file or shared library mini_racer`


Though I see the ` /home/*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/mini_racer-0.2.4/ext/mini_racer_extension/` folder and its contents.

Comment: Can you please do `ruby -v` inside `~/Desktop/Studies/react-on-rails-demo` and check the ruby version you have for react-on-rails-demo project. Or you can try `bundle exec gem which mini_racer`. Or do `rvm use ruby@2.5.1` and then run `gem which mini_racer`. Let me know if its working or not.

Comment: These were the outputs:

`ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57`

`bundle exec gem which mini_racer
Could not find gem 'mini_racer' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

`rvm use ruby@2.5.1
ruby-2.5.1 - #gemset created /home/*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@2.5.1
ruby-2.5.1 - #generating 2.5.1 wrappers...........
Using /home/*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1 with gemset 2.5.1`

`gem which mini_racer
ERROR:  Can't find Ruby library file or shared library mini_racer`

Comment: I'm trying to install the React on Rails framework. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bjScw60FBk&index=3&list=PL5VAKH-U1M6dj84BApfUtvBjvF-0-JfEU

Comment: Add mini_racer to your gemfile and do a `bundle`, then check `gem which mini_racer` I think it should work after this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185007/discussion-between-eurodo061-and-el-anonimo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out
`# mini_racer', platforms: :ruby` in the Gemfile then installed `mini_racer` with `sudo gem install mini_racer`. It seems to work now. Though `mini_racer` remained commented out in the Gemfile.